# ReactJS How to transfer data between pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still new to React.

I was wondering, how do I transfer data from let's say "Main Page" to another page to display the results?

I think it has something to do with props? But I'm not entirely sure.

My MainPage has input/select tags that takes in name, value, selections from user and dates.

I want to be able to grab all those information and output it in another page called "DisplayResults" and maybe use the data for other things, maybe create a table with the information.

Thanks very much for your help!

**This is my app.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var {Route, Router, IndexRoute, hashHistory} = require('react-router');
var Main = require('Main');
var MainPage = require('MainPage');
var About = require('About');
// Load foundation
require('style!css!foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.css')
$(document).foundation();
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Main}>
      <Route path="about" component={About}/>
      <IndexRoute component={MainPage}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Have you gone through any React tutorials? The answer might be a bit involved...but basically you need to create components that have their own routes, and you pass the data to them in `props` or as part of the global state tree (if you are using `redux`, for example)...

Comment: You can pass properties to child components, and as @user1370384 mentioned you need to use  flux, redux, mobx ..etc to do it properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few different ways... Good option would be to use some state management layer like Redux or MobX

A simple one is to have your `Main` component save those data in its state and pass it to the other pages as props. Since you're using `react-router` you'll need to clone the `this.props.children` in your `Main` component to add the additional props like the data and the function that sets the data.

Your `Main` component would probably look something like

```
class Main extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      this.state = {
         data: 'some default data',
      }
   }

   updateData(data) {
      this.setState({ data });
   }

   render() {
     return <div>
        <Header />
        {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { data: this.state.data, setData: this.updateData })}
     </div>
   }
}

class MainPage extends Component {

   render() {
      return <div>
         <input type="text" onChange={e => this.props.setData({ field: e.target.value })} />
         <Link to="/DisplayResults">Go to Results</Link>
      </div>
   }
}

class DisplayResults extends Component {
   render() {
       return <div>
         {this.props.data.field}
       </div>
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi @jpdelatorre How to perform the same operation with functional component

Answer (score 7):

Technically React creates a single page application, therefore there is no other page to pass data to.

However, I believe you might be talking about passing data into `components`. I always structure my React applications into `container` and `component` folders. The container folder is where all the logic components are located, and the component folder is where all the UI components are located.

One of the things that makes React so intuitive is that you can easily pass data from parent components to children components via props. In other words, my logic components pass data to the UI components via props.

For example suppose I want my logic component called Dashboard to pass organization data to my UI component `MyChildComponent`, I would do something like this:

`containers/DashBoard/index.js`

```
export class DashBoard extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      organizations: null,
    };
    this.rowCallback = this.rowCallback.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    <MyChildComponent orgs={this.state.organizations} />
  }
}
```

`components/MyChildComponent/index.js`

```
export class MyChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    <div>
      {this.props.orgs}
    </div>
  }
}
```

This is just one way to handle passing in data. You could also pass in values while routing between logic components, or use a flux library like `redux` to create state variables, etc..

> Please note that my code excerpts make use of es6, and needs a babel
>   compiler. I also prefer using functions for UI components when
>   possible as I believe that is the React Way