# Fetch data once before render, and share it between exported static HTML pages in Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch, next.js

I have a small next.js project, which is served by an Express.js application. It works by exporting the Next app into static HTML (`next export`), and the Express server serves it as static files from a public directory.

Now the problem is, that the Next app has multiple (static) routes (`/page1`, `/page2`, ...), but nearly all pages need the same data which I fetch from an api (client side).

Now these pages look like:

```
export default function PageN() {
  const [ data, setData ] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(...).then((r) => {
      setData(r)
    })
  }, [])
  // ...
  if (data) {
    // render page
  } else {
    // render 'loading'
  }
}
```

After loading the app, and navigating from `/` to `/page1` it fetches the data from an api. But it does that again, if navigate to `/page2`. The ideal solution would be fetching the required data somewhere on load, store it globally, and make it available for every page. Maybe in `_app.js`. I have tried experimenting with `getStaticProps` and `getInitialProps` in `_app.js`, but I couldn't make it work.

Is there a way to fetch data only once, and share it between every page, but still keep the ability to export the app into static HTML?

Comment: When navigating from /page1 to /page2 is there a full page load or is the navigation done only on the client so it doesn't  touch the server again? Also maybe this helps  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238637/react-router-how-to-pass-data-between-pages-in-react

Comment: @Molda navigation is done on client side, no server touching required. Only for those fetch-es

Comment: Also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966762/reactjs-how-to-transfer-data-between-pages/41967180

Comment: @Molda data transfer between pages could solve the issue, but I feel like the ultimate solution would be storing the fetched data globally somehow