# Transferring data from one page to another

Tags: reactjs

I have a page called Games in my React app and my React Routes are in the App.js file. On that Games page, if I click myButton, I want it to go to another page called Analyze Game and then populate some variables there. But when I normally open Analyze Game (without clicking myButton), it defines and populates a bunch of state and variables. The reason is so that you can analyze a game you manually enter, rather than picking from the list on the Games page. So I am a bit puzzled on how I can transfer the game data from the Games page to the Analyze Game page and then populate some variables there only if someone came from the games page.

I found this link that shows you can use history.push to get some data that was passed from one page to another: [React-router - How to pass data between pages in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238637/react-router-how-to-pass-data-between-pages-in-react)

But how do you then only populate the variables on the Analyze Game page if you came from the games page?

Would you set a flag or something? What is best practice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966762/reactjs-how-to-transfer-data-between-pages/41966943

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59701050/how-to-pass-data-from-a-page-to-another-page-using-react-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question, and normally can be done in two ways. I'll briefly mention them. *Of course, there're other ways ;)*

##### props

*React* likes props, so if you can solve it with that, that should be your first approach.

```
  const App = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(...)
    
    return (
      <Router>
         <Route1 render={() => <GamePage value={value} />} />
         <Route2 render={() => <AnalyzePage value={value} />} />
      </Router>
    )
  }
```

If you want to change this value inside either Game or Analyze, pass the `setValue` inside as well.

##### context

If you have very nested components inside the route, sometimes people like to use a context.

```
  const App = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(...)
    
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={{ value, setValue}}>
        <Router>
          <Route1 render={() => <GamePage />} />
          <Route2 render={() => <AnalyzePage />} />
        </Router>
      </Context.Provider>
    )
  }

  const ComponentInsideGame = () => {
    const { value } = useContext(Context)
    ...
  }
```

##### global

If it turns out you want to send something behind *React*, for instance you don't want to trigger render at all for these shared data. You could do a global context with a ref.

```
  const App = () => {
    const ref = useRef({
      gameConfiguration: ...,
      runGame: () => {}
    ))
    
    return (
      <Router>
         <Route1 render={() => <GamePage />} />
         <Route2 render={() => <AnalyzePage />} />
      </Router>
    )
  }

  const ComponentInsideGame = () => {
    const { current } = useContext(Context)
    current.gameConfiguration = {...}
    current.runGame()
    ...
  }
```

##### route state

The link you provided is another way with browser state, however this actually isn't a react way, it's a browser way IMHO. But you know what, anyway works for you is fine :)

Comment: Thank you for that detail. Very useful to see the different ways. I have learnt from how you have structured that, by raising state to the App level, rather than page level.